# Wicket gives an error when I changed cookie name to custom

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wicket

I changed the cookie name to custom one. After that, Wicket gives an error when the page loads first time. (There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)). When I reload the page, there are no errors, because the cookie has already been created.

Spring boot config

```
 server.session.cookie.name=mySessionId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `org.apache.wicket.util.string.Strings.java`:

```
    /**
     * The name of the parameter used to keep the session id.
     * The Servlet specification mandates <em>jsessionid</em> but the web containers
     * provide ways to set a custom one, e.g. <em>sid</em>.
     * Since Wicket doesn't have access to the web container internals the name should be set explicitly.
     */
     public static final String SESSION_ID_PARAM_NAME = 
        System.getProperty("wicket.jsessionid.name", "jsessionid");
```

Try to start your web container with `-Dwicket.jsessionid.name=mySessionId` and see whether it helps.

Comment: I just realized an issue with this: Use of upper case name: e.g. JSESSIONID-prod does not work due to Strings.stripJSessionId (Wicket 6.29.0) performing a toLowerCase on the given URL before attempting to find the index of the SESSION_ID_PARAM. It won't find the session param if you have any uppercase chars even though Tomcat supports uppercase JSESSIONID names. Was very excited to finally find the cause of this obscure issue :)

Comment: The above issue will be the reason why this person had issues with changing the session param name here:
http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Changed-JSESSIONID-Results-in-Wicket-Exception-td4664202.html because he used a name with upper case letters like I did.